# How do you efficiently decrypt information with no noticeable lag time?

Tags: performance, encryption, language-agnostic

My computer has a program called *Bit Locker* which encrypts the entire hard drive.  The hard drive is about 500 gigabytes.  However I don't notice any real lag time at all between this computer and another (unencrypted) one when performing the same read action (say, for example, loading a large file).

I'm curious how this is possible.  If everything on the disk is heavily encrypted, shouldn't it take a noticeable process time to decrypt everything before you can read or view it?  Obviously everything on the disk isn't automatically decrypted at boot time, because decrypting 500 gigabytes of data every time would cause a ridiculous wait time at start up.  I suppose there could be a local, decrypted cache somewhere, but wouldn't that defeat the purpose of the encryption to begin with?

Note: I'm not asking how this specific program accomplishes it; that's just an example.  Rather, I'm curious as to how an encrypted disk can still read and write efficiently without much -- or any -- human-noticeable lag time, because apparently it is possible.

Thank you!

**CLARIFICATION:** I know that individual blocks of data can be encrypted/decrypted separately from one another.  However, it seems that if every time you perform a read (by opening a PDF or a Word file or whatever) that you *also* have to run the decryption algorithm on the data being read then this would produce a noticeable lag time (e.g., a much "slower" computer).  This doesn't seem to be the case, though.  Why and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you read a block from disk, the CPU spends a lot of time doing absolutely nothing, waiting for the I/O to complete.

Assuming that the CPU isn't busy with other things, you can fit quite a lot of processing of the previous block into the time spent waiting for the next block. The overall time to read a reasonable amount of data is barely affected by the decryption, provided that the decryption is fast enough. "Fast enough" depends on CPU speed relative to I/O speed, and how many idle cores the CPU has during the read.

I guess BitLocker's decryption is fast enough - in the case of opening a PDF there's a second possibility, that the cost of decryption might be trivial compared with the cost of rendering the page. So even if the overall time to read the file is increased, you wouldn't necessarily notice.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of encrypting the entire drive as a single stream, one can encrypt individual *blocks* of data. This works because the encryption does not change the *size* of the data, but rather only its *content*. These blocks can then be read separately and then decrypted on the fly.

Comment: Right, I understand that.  But when that decryption algorithm runs on those individual blocks, shouldn't that cause a noticeable lag time?

Comment: That depends on how you define "noticeable". There are many fast encryption algorithms in existence.